# Is, in the "double point-source experiment", an interference pattern visible in the vertical direction?

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment

A double-slit experiment is performed where the slits are replaced by small circular apertures with a very small diameter (compared to the distance to the screen). An interference pattern is observed in the horizontal direction. What about the vertical direction? If we move up from some point on the horizontal on the screen (where the horizontal interference pattern is seen), will not a pattern be seen of constructive and destructive interference, caused by a changing phase difference between the two waves coming from the point sources?

Comment: Aren't hyperbolic fringes formed for point-source interference? I feel that should be the case, considering that the region of the screen where bright fringes are observed (of a particular order) would have a constant phase difference of $2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

In a realistic situation, you would observe on a 2D screen, a combination of two circular aperture diffraction patterns.